# solr stats error: Can't calculate stats on a PointField without docValues

Tags: solr

I am trying to get the min/max price of a search with solr 7.x in order to populate a min/max price filter following this tuturial:

https://qavi.tech/get-minimum-and-maximum-price-in-solr/

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-stats-component.html

field:

```
<field name="price" type="tint" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
```

Solr returns the following error:

> "msg": "Can't calculate stats on a PointField without docValues",
>       "code": 400

What could be the reason for this and do I have to enable this in solr_conf?

```
<searchComponent name="stats"     class="solr.StatsComponent" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may depend on how the fieldType is defined in your schema.

`tint` used to be the preferred name for `TrieIntField` implementations that supports sorting, statistics computation, etc. without having to enable docValues, so it could be that your field type implements another class (a PointField class) that actually does rely on docValues to achieve the same goals.

For example it might be an `IntPointField` :

> Integer field (32-bit signed integer). This class encodes int values
>   using a "Dimensional Points" based data structure that allows for very
>   efficient searches for specific values, or ranges of values. For
>   single valued fields, docValues="true" must be used to enable sorting.

Well, in fact it *should be* an `IntPointField` since **as of Solr 7.0, Trie fields are [deprecated](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/field-types-included-with-solr.html) in favor of Point fields :**

> TrieField takes a type parameter to define the specific class of Trie* field to use. Use an appropriate Point Field type instead :
>
> T̶r̶i̶e̶D̶a̶t̶e̶F̶i̶e̶l̶d̶     > DatePointField
>   ̶T̶r̶i̶e̶D̶o̶u̶b̶l̶e̶F̶i̶e̶l̶d̶    > DoublePointField
>   T̶r̶i̶e̶F̶l̶o̶a̶t̶F̶i̶e̶l̶d̶     > FloatPointField
>   T̶r̶i̶e̶I̶n̶t̶F̶i̶e̶l̶d̶      > IntPointField
>   T̶r̶i̶e̶L̶o̶n̶g̶F̶i̶e̶l̶d̶     > LongPointField

Now, the error says *"Can't calculate stats on a PointField without docValues"*, so either :

- `price` is not the field involved here because its type `tint` would refer (usually refers) to TrieIntField, not PointField. That means another PointField not using docValues is responsible for the error.
- `price` is a PointField so first its type should be `pint` or whatever the fieldType's name it refers to is, but not `tint` (unless the fieldType itself is wrongly named), and secondly it needs docValues enabled for calculating stats.

So, settting a proper field/fieldType definition in schema.xml, explicitly referring to an IntPointField type, and enabling docValues (adding `docValues="true"` to the field or field type definition) should help. For example :

```
<fieldType name="pint" class="solr.IntPointField" docValues="true"/>
<field name="price" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
```

Comment: Thank you! I had exidently posted the wrong field definition from an old conf file. The type is point field, but it was missing the docValues=true. Changed, restarted solr, reindexed. Works. Now a question remains, do I need to enable: <searchComponent name="stats"     class="solr.StatsComponent" />? As I had do add: stats=true manually to the query. In PHP I am issuing: $this->query->addStatsField( 'price'); which results in a query without stats=true.

Comment: You only need to add the 'stats' component in your requestHandler if you have an explicit components list definition (with `<arr name="components">...</arr>`) otherwise Solr will executes [default components](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/requesthandlers-and-searchcomponents-in-solrconfig.html#RequestHandlersandSearchComponentsinSolrConfig-DefaultComponents), including 'stats'. You can also enable/disable it at query time in PHP with `$SolrQuery->setstats($flag)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, that was the case. I enabled now on query time and successfully integrated into my application. Have a great day!